# How can I add --exclude-from '/root/exclude-list.txt' to the rsync command and not get an error

Tags: ssh, rsync

this is the command I use now:

rsync –delete –stats -vae ssh 12.123.123.12:/backup/cpbackup/daily /home/file/

In this example how can I add: –exclude-from ‘/root/exclude-list.txt’

When I try to add it like this:

rsync –delete –stats -vae –exclude-from ‘/root/exclude-list.txt’ ssh 12.123.123.12:/backup/cpbackup/daily /home/file/

But I just get this error: rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1201) [sender=3.0.6]

Thanks, my goal is to exclude these files with our back up server:

error_log
*.core
/mail/new/*
daily/*/homedir/mail/new/*
*.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ssh` is an argument to the `-e` option. You'll have to add other options before or after the option and its argument, not in between.

Comment: That worked! rsync --delete --stats --exclude-from '/root/exclude-list.txt' -vae ssh 12.123.123.12:/backup/cpbackup/daily /home/file/